# Using built in libpng in wxWidgets 3.0-rc1/rc2 causes an assert on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
static const unsigned char image_png[] = ...;
auto bitmap = wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData(image_png, WXSIZEOF(image_png));
```

`bitmap.IsOk()` returns `false` if wxWidgets was built with builtin version of libpng. Otherwise it works fine. Is there a solution for using builtin libpng?

Comment: In general, it's recommended to use the system PNG library under Linux, this e.g. ensures that your application will profit from any security updates to it coming from the system package manager. Why do you insist on using the built-in version?

Comment: I had to switch to using system libpng. But working fine on Debian it is still a problem on Ubuntu to use builtin libpng